# how to apply two style class to single button in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I need to apply two style class for a button and I could not merge them and use it as new style class.Is their any other way around?

Comment: Have you tried simply adding both of them? `Node#getStyleClass` returns a list of strings...

Comment: I used it like this and it worked                             
  <styleClass>  <String fx:value="p2" />
   <String fx:value="txtGray" />
 </styleClass>

Answer (score 3):

You can add several styleClasses to a node by:

`node.getStyleClass().addAll("style1", "style2")`

or in a fxml file:

`<Button styleClass="style1, style2">`